# No FontFamily element found in FontFamilyCollection

Tags: wpf

My WPF application suddenly fails with the following exception:

> System.IO.FileFormatException: No FontFamily element found in
>   FontFamilyCollection that matches current OS or greater: Windows7SP1

I've tried different OS but it's happening only on Windows 7 with SP1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found out that the exception is connected to the latest security update KB4055532. When this update is uninstalled on Windows 7 SP1 then the problem disappear.

Comment: Definitely caused by the update. I am receiving user reports with the same error popping up after installing KB4055532

Comment: fwiw - installing KB4056894 also triggers this exception when starting Powershell ISE

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft released an official statement about this issue here (includes workarounds):
https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/53

Comment: thanks, yep on that announcement, this link is microsofts option1 and it fixed it instantly, no restart was required. https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=4074906

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not allowed to comment:
Answer by 'user2250152' is correct.
@Comment by @Lieven Keersmaekers:
'fwiw - installing KB4056894 also triggers this exception when starting Powershell ISE':
I really doubt this.
I'm dealing with this 'KB4055532' issue for 2 days now on all in all 8 machines. But after having installed 'KB4056894' there were no issues with starting Powershell ISE.
This only started to happen after installing 'KB4055532'.
And uninstalling this 'KB4055532' (but still having 'KB4056894' on the machines) resolves the issue with Powershell.
Btw:
There is a hint on the following site (and a way to 'fix' the issue):
https://ngb.to/threads/32709-Microsoft-Patchday-Januar-2018-KB4055532-NET-Font-Probleme.
The issue comes from a '*.CompositeFont' file that gets replaced by the update and which is then missing information for Windows 7. This makes programs based on WPF using functions to determine FontFamily fail/crash.
Effectively I'm quite sure it is only the file 'GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont' that must be exchanged to temporarily fix this issue.

Comment: fwiw: Powershell ISE worked yesterday, KB4056894 was installed yesterday *(wmic qfe list)* and Powershell ISE doesn't work today. Taking a crashdump from powershell_ise shows that it's the "FontFamiliyCollection" error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error with MarkdownPad2.  With the information from [.NET Framework January 2018 Rollup Known Issue KB4074906 - "TypeInitializationException" or "FileFormatException" error in WPF applications](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/53) (thanks @Boris!), I used the manual repair option to download and replace the corrupted font (installed by Microsoft's update) and it solved the problem.

The exception looks like this:

`The invocation of the constructor on type 'MarkdownPad2.UserControls.MarkdownEditor' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception. 
---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Media.Fonts' threw an exception. 
---> System.IO.FileFormatException: No FontFamily element found in FontFamilyCollection that matches current OS or greater: Windows7SP1`

Damaging a font during an upgrade seems like an inexcusable error.  Apparently Microsoft agrees, as they closed the tech note with this comment:

> All updates are extensively tested before they are provided to you. We are investigating the gap in our testing and will resolve that for our next release.